# Function to calculate the difference between sum of squares and square of sums

Tags: python, sum

I am trying to Write a function called `sum_square_difference` which takes a number n and returns the difference between the sum of the squares of the ﬁrst n natural numbers and the square of their sum.

I think i know how to write a function that defines the sum of squares

```
def sum_of_squares(numbers):
    total = 0
    for num in numbers:
        total += (num ** 2)
    return(total)
```

I have tried to implement a square of sums function:

```
def square_sum(numbers):  
    total = 0
    for each in range: 
        total = total + each
    return total**2
```

I don't know how to combine functions to tell the difference and i don't know if my functions are correct.

Any suggestions please? I am using Python 3.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function can be written with pure math like this:

[image: The formula]

Translated into Python:

```
def square_sum_difference(n):
    return int((3*n**2 + 2*n) * (1 - n**2) / 12)
```

---

The formula is a simplification of two other formulas:

```
def square_sum_difference(n):
    return int(n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 - (n*(n+1)/2)**2)
```

`n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6` is the formula described [here](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm), which returns the sum of the squares of the first `n` natural numbers.

`(n*(n+1)/2))**2` uses the triangle number formula, which is the sum of the first `n` natural numbers, and which is then squared.

---

This can also be done with the built in `sum` function. Here it is:

```
def sum_square_difference(n):
    r = range(1, n+1)  # first n natural numbers
    return sum(i**2 for i in r) - sum(r)**2
```

The `range(1, n+1)` produces an iterator of the first `n` natural numbers.

```
>>> list(range(1, 4+1))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`sum(i**2 for i in r)` returns the sum of the squares of the numbers in r, and `sum(r)**2` returns the square of the sum of the numbers in r.

Comment: Don't see why this was -1'd. I +1'd

Comment: Anyone have a working link to the math solution?

Answer (score 5):

# As beta says,
# (sum(i))^2 - (sum(i^2)) is very easy to calculate :)
# A = sum(i) = i*(i+1)/2
# B = sum(i^2) = i*(i+1)*(2*i + 1)/6
# A^2 - B = i(i+1)(3(i^2) - i - 2) / 12
# :)
# no loops... just a formula !**

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where it pays to do the math beforehand. You can derive **closed-form solutions** for both the sum of the squares and the square of the sum. Then the code is trivial (and O(1)).

Need help with the two solutions?

Comment: and now I'll never forget to do some maths before solving a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_square_difference(n):
    r = range(1,n+1)
    sum_of_squares =  sum(map(lambda x: x*x, r))
    square_sum = sum(r)**2
    return sum_of_squares - square_sum
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby language you can achieve this in this way

```
def diff_btw_sum_of_squars_and_squar_of_sum(from=1,to=100) # use default values from 1..100. 
((1..100).inject(:+)**2) -(1..100).map {|num| num ** 2}.inject(:+)
end

diff_btw_sum_of_squars_and_squar_of_sum #call for above method
```